# Complex integration around a singularity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to integrate the function $f(z)=$$\frac{5}{z^2}$ from -3 to 3 and I am supposed to develop a closed region that avoids the origin and use the analyticity of the function in this region to integrate the function in a way that is simpler than parametrizing along some path. Any suggestions?

Comment: "From -3 to 3" ...on the real axis or what?

Comment: the path goes from -3 to $i$ and from $i$ to 3

Comment: @Frederick, and then why don't you **explicitly** say that in your question?!

Comment: The user is asking for suggestions, may be he is new and learning! And it got downvoted -2, this site is not exclusively for CERN type mathematical questions!  +1 from me!

Comment: I didn't know that the path mattered. This is new material for me.

Comment: I was under the impression that if I make a closed interval around the origin that the integral would be zero from the properties of closed contours

Comment: This is complex analysis, @Frederick: stuff from 2nd-3th undergraduate year. You should know better> if you do not know whether the path matters or not, why did you omit info?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'll make sure to be more explicit from now on

Answer (score 0):

Do line integrals as usual in real analysis, i.e. parametrization and stuff:

$$\begin{align*}\text{From $\;-3\;$ to}\;\,i:&\;\;\; -3\le x\le0\;,\;\;\;y=\frac13x+1\\{}\\
\text{From $\;i\;$ to}\;\,3:&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0\le x\le3\;,\;\;y=-\frac13x+1\end{align*}$$

So you integral is

$$\int\limits_{-3}^0\frac5{x^2-y^2+2xyi}dxdy+\int\limits_0^3\frac5{x^2-y^2+2xyi}dxdy$$

Answer (score 0):

You can pick any other piecewise smooth path $\alpha$ from -3 to 3 in the complex plane so that the sum of the path you've given, which I'll call $\beta$ (piecewise linear from -3 to $i$ and then $i$ to 3), and $\alpha$ is simple and does not enclose the origin.  Then Cauchy's theorem says that $\int_{\alpha + \beta} \frac{5}{z^2}dz=0$.

You have $$\int_{\alpha + \beta} \frac{5}{z^2}dz = \int_{\alpha} \frac{5}{z^2}dz +\int_{\beta} \frac{5}{z^2}dz=0 \rightarrow-\int_{\alpha} \frac{5}{z^2}dz = \int_{\beta} \frac{5}{z^2}dz$$

You get to pick any $\alpha$ satisying the condition in the first sentence above to make things easier on yourself for the integration.  A simple choice for $-\alpha$ is to go from -3 to $-\frac{1}{2}$ along the real line, then follow the arc of the circle centered at the origin of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ clockwise to $\frac{1}{2}$, and then follow the real line to 3.

You end up with: $$\int_{\beta} \frac{5}{z^2}dz=\int_{-3}^{1/2} \frac{5}{x^2}dx+\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{5}{((1/2)e^{i \theta})^2}\cdot (1/2)ie^{i \theta}d\theta+\int_{1/2}^{3} \frac{5}{x^2}dx$$

The three integrals on the RHS above are all pretty simple to compute.